# PHP Excel, Read excel file with chart and write back but the chart is missing

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet, phpoffice-phpspreadsheet

```
            //load spreadsheet
            $spreadsheet = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::load(public_path("default_.xlsx"));
            //change it
            $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
            $array = $sheet->getChartNames();

            info($array);

            $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
            $writer->save($this->file_name_download);
```

somebody help, this's my code to read the existing file xlsx, and this file has a chart, but this does not exist when I read it with PHP.

I'm trying many ways to read this file, but still no chart.

Comment: What is the error you receive?

Comment: It's no error, just the chart doesn't exist in the xlsx file, that's the file I read and am trying to edit. I mean, the chart already existed in an xlsx file, and this disappeared when I read.

Comment: Read this: https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/issues/3767

Comment: @Olivier: $array is array of the name of all chart in the xlsx, but it's empty when I read xlsx, the file that already had the chart

Comment: Charts are not loaded (or saved) by default. You must explicitly tell the Reader and Writer to include charts when loading and saving a file. https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/reading-and-writing-to-file/#readerwriter-flags